# "I have been there (for) once". Is the 'for' needed?

Tags: usage

My friend told me that the 'for' is not needed. Is that correct? If it is, I remember seeing usages like "I will wait for you for once." somewhere else, but how is the 'for' used differently in these two sentences?

Comment: This question is better suited to the ELL site.

Comment: You can either say "I have been there once" or "I have been there for the first time." You would used the second to indicate the importance of your first visit to the place.

Comment: Ok, so, if a person never tends to believe you, you might say: "For once, please believe me". That is how for once is used. for once: this time which is a first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you only went there one time? Then you should say "I was there once" or "I went there once" . Don't use "for" in this context.

"For once" means you don't usually do something, but this time you did. Like "For once, I brought my reusable bags to the grocery store!"

Comment: In that case, when am I supposed to use for to express how many times?

Comment: Please see my updated explanation.

Comment: Please add a reference supporting the rather unexpected implication of using 'for once'. // Perhaps sentence-initial examples ('For once, Hamilton is not the favourite to take the Drivers' Championship') are an easier way in.

Comment: If you want a reference, Collins Cobuild has an entry for "for once": " used to emphasize that something happens on this particular occasion, especially if it has never happened before, and may never happen again." https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-once